# Silex - How to process template includes separately

Tags: symfony, templates, include, silex

I've got a Twig base template like so:

```
{% include "./partials/navigation.html" %}

<!-- Main Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</div>
```

I also have a route controller which is outputting the response content to the page using twig:

```
return template->render('path/to/teplate', args());
```

where args[] array is all the data needed for this bit: (different on every page)

```
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

However my sidebar is being built separately through a menu builder class, and now it needs to render the results of building the menu to my template and populating **./partials/navigation.html**.

An easy solution for me is to just append the results of the Menu Builder to the returned response of every controller (I can use a base controller class to do this as this menu appears on every page). However something about this feels unclean as if I have to render the same header/footer every time as well I'll have to be append all 3 outputs to the response. (maybe that is okay?)

Is there a better way of rendering several includes worth of content which each need their own DB lookups and other server-side logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. They are called sub requests. Read the [documentation here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-the-new-fragment-sub-framework).

Comment: I see I can use `{{ render(controller('Bundle:controller:action')) }}` to access my controller. I have my controllers registered as services so would this be a case of using 'service.controller:action'?

Comment: Okay in Silex I was able to use render(path('route_name')), which means I need to register and create a route for my sidebar. This seems a bit odd, but if its necessary then I guess it will do.

Comment: Sorry not too familiar with Silex specifically. Looks like they do things a little differently as you discovered. Here is the more relevant documentation -- http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html